# Creating Non-session Cookies with Symfony HttpFoundation

Tags: symfony, cookies, session-cookies

What do I need to do to create cookies with the HttpFoundation component that will not expire with the session?

**Background**:

I am using Symfony's HttpFoundation Component. I am not using the entire Symfony framework.  I am able to store and retrieve session cookies using the component.

Whenever I change the cookie expire time to something other than 0, they will not save.

This will create a session cookie:

```
new Cookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_value, 0, '/', null, false, false);
```

This will not create a cookie:

```
new Cookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_value, 10000, '/', null, false, false);
```

Comment: Could you please post exact HTTP response (headers) generated by both codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the feedback from Crozin, I looked at the post headers and found the problem.

Header for expire time of 0:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\nDate: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 12:49:50 GMT\r\nLocation: stories\r\nSet-Cookie: cerberus=email_add%40yahoo.com+53d7986e073ef; path=/\r\n
```

Header for expire time of 10000:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\nDate: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 12:50:53 GMT\r\nLocation: stories\r\nSet-Cookie: cerberus=email_add%40yahoo.com+53d798ad3696e; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 02:46:40 GMT; path=/\r\n
```

The problem, I was putting the wrong type of value for the expire time, it should have been like this

```
$expire  =  time() + (3600 * 48);
new Cookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_value, expire, '/', null, false, false);
```

With the correct results of:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\nDate: Tue, 29 Jul 2014 12:56:58 GMT\r\nLocation: stories\r\nSet-Cookie: cerberus=email_add%40yahoo.com+53d79a1a3f335; expires=Thu, 31-Jul-2014 12:56:58 GMT; path=/\r\n
```